# SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'raw.githubusercontent.com'

Tags: command-line, networking, server, 20.04, ssl

I was having issues installing NPM packages on my (new) ubuntu IPv6 VPS until I added this line to `/etc/hosts`

```
2606:4700::6810:1723 registry.npmjs.org
```

I was then able to install NPM packages.

Next, I saw `Couldn't connect to the server` when trying to install NVM, using this command:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash
```

Trying to copy the prior fix, I added the following line to `/etc/hosts`

```
2606:4700::6810:1723 raw.githubusercontent.com
```

Now as I rerun the NVM install command, the error has changed:

```
curl: (60) SSL: no alternative certificate subject 
name matches target host name 'raw.githubusercontent.com'

More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server 
and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more
 about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned
 above.
```

Anyone know how to resolve this issue?